# how to check HTTP persistent connection using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, keep-alive

I have initialized a cURL handle and using the same handle i'm executing multiple URLs to the same server. though  i'm getting response connection as keep-alive for every execution, how do i check if the same connection is used for second time also and the connection is not initialized again? because if i delay execution for more than the keep alive timeout, still the response connection is keep alive.
Is there any unique ID for the persistent connections?